# Unity: multiple colliders collide, but only one should collide

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to implement a keyboard in unity. Therefore, I've created a key prefab with a box collider and no rigidbody and a circle with spherecollider and rigidbody. I am using the circle to represent a finger typing on the keys.
The problem I am facing is that the `OnCollisionEnter(Collission collission)` method in the *KeyCollissionHandler.cs* script gets called even if the colliders of circle and key are not even close.

To visualize the problem take a look at the following screenshots.

Here you can see the pressed keys in the game scene, the grey & yellow keys are collided with the finger and the white ones are not collided.
[Playmode with triggered colliders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xej0L.png)

Of course first I checked the size of the colliders and set them to a very small size of 0.5x0.5x0.5 for the key box colliders and 0.1 radius for the circle sphere collider. The gameobjects of key and circle are also relativly small (key: 0.135x0.08x0.15, circle: 0.01x0.01x0.01).

Summary: Colliders collide even if there is no gameobject near to it. Why does this happen?
Please just ask if you need more info, I will provide the informations you need asap.

*KeyCollissionHandler.cs* attached to all keys:

```
using Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Input;
using Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Utilities;
using System;
using UnityEngine;

public class KeyCollisionHandler : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string keyLetter; //Holds the letter of the actual key
    public bool editorConfig = false; //For debugging purposes

    private void Awake()
    {
        //Some awake stuff
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if (EventManager.instance != null)
        {
            EventManager.instance.OnAddCollission(this);
        }        
    }

    private void OnCollisionExit(Collision collision)
    {
        
        if (EventManager.instance != null)
        {
            EventManager.instance.OnRemoveCollission(this);
        }
    }
}
```

All the script does is call other actions to handle the key input into a textmesh and the colloring you saw in [the first screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xej0L.png).

[Unity Inspector Screenshot of the circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KevXn.png)

[Collider of Circle in scene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3y2f.png)

[Unity Inspector of the Key "R"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KsTZ.png)

[Collider of Key "R" which is triggered but should not be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrzYq.png)

Cheers

Comment: Have you checked what is colliding with the key?  What does your eventmanager do. Why are you adding/removing collisions ?

Comment: Thank your for your comment! I have to check again, but it has to be the circle because there is no other gameobject around it and the circle is the only gameobject with a rigidbody. The eventmanager only invokes all my actions in the scene and I am adding/removing collissions because I am calculating the distances to the collissions to the circle to determine which is the closest. That was my first approach to handle all these collissions, but that is not exact enough. The yellow key in the first screenshot is the one I manually calculated as the closest key.

Comment: @BugFinder I checked the collission again and all the keys are colliding with the circle.

Comment: Then something else is going on. Like your key colliders are too big or tall or such. Or how you move the ball. Is trigger all of them

Comment: So i fixed it. Basically it was the collission offset that caused the problem, because my keys and the sphere where quite small. Thank you  @BugFinder for your answer!